# How to Delete Restoring Database

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I am running log shipping with SQL server 2008 R2.

I have a situation where the secondary database drive ran out of space and was not applying log shipping transaction logs.

The way I want to fix this is delete the databases at the secondary and configure log shipping from scratch.

The problem I have now is that my secondary databases are in the restoring state, and I cannot delete them. How can I proceed?

For instance if I try to take them offline I get the error,

```
ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while the database is in the Restoring state.
```

Comment: you can't issue an alter command on a restoring database, will need to do a drop.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbname 
FROM DISK = 'dbname .bak'
WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY --force restore
```

or just

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbname WITH RECOVERY
```

the `REPLACE` Overwrite the existing database, do it only if you are sure you want to override your existing database as you mentioned you dont care to delete it

*RESTORE WITH RECOVERY is the default behavior which leaves the database ready for use by rolling back the uncommitted transactions. Additional transaction logs cannot be restored.*

That should bring the database online. Then you can delete it & try again.

Comment: I believe what you are saying should have worked. My solution though was to restart the sql service and then deleting the databases worked after that.

Comment: true, while service is off, deleting the transaction logs will always create a new one. all the best

Answer (score 4):

Best way as i have done with this problem is write this command 'drop database [database name]' and then create new one with same name and then restore database from another .bak file because .bak file is corrupted or faulty.

Comment: There is no mention in the question about corrupted backups.